# Some problems rotating single pages

Tags: header-footer, rotating

Good afternoon,

I need to rotate just a few pages of a document I am writing and I firstly experimented this problem: \usepackage{lscape} did not rotate the page at all but the content inside it. After looking it up on the internet, I found that, since I was compiling with pdflatex, I would have to use \usepackage{pdflscape} instead.

However, since this package fixed the problem of not rotating the page itself but only the content within, the page number appears now on the «left side» of the page (it is actually the bottom, because the page is rotated) and the header is on the «right side». So my question is the following:

**How can I set the page number at the bottom of the horizontal page and the header on the top of the horizontal page?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: this is not longer a simple "rotating". You are actually asking how to change the complete page layout from a portrait to a landscape layout. How to do this depends a lot on your current layout.

Comment: The fact that "the page number appears now on the «left side» of the page ... and the header is on the «right side»" is an artifact of the way the pdf viewer displays the document. When printed as a hardcopy, the header and footer lines will be where they belong, i.e, at the top and bottom if you view the entire page in "portrait" format.

Comment: Thanks both, but I fear Ulrike Fischer understood better what I pretend to do. So, do you know more or lest how to try it? I honestly have no idea about this particular stuff since I never did it before...